# jquery according infront of html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

So like the title mentions, I made an accordion that shows some content when clicked on but hides the side menu drop down.

[Here's a link to to an image that shows the problem.](http://i.imgur.com/wkXBg2I.png)

I tried going into the css and adding a z-index of -1 and it worked but then the accordion wasn't clickable.

I tried adding object.style.zIndex="-1" to the java script and that didn't work either, just kinda demolished the accordion and showed all the content.

I'm using jquery UI with a custom theme and I added this bit of javascript on the html document.

```
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
  active:false,
  collapsible: true
 });
});
$(function(){
$("#accordion").accordion({
    heightStyle:"fill" 
 });
 });
 $(function(){
$( "#accordion-resizer" ).resizable({
  minHeight: 140,
  minWidth: 200,
  resize: function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "refresh" );
  }
 });
 });
```

This is the css I'm using and the minor change I did that worked but wouldn't allow the user to click on anything.

```
#accordion-resizer{
padding: 10px;
width: 700px;
height: auto;
}
.ui-widget-content{
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Like I mentioned before, I'm using jqueryUI with a custom theme. Hope this helps. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
.ui-widget-content{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Maybe the positioning will allow the Z-index to work?

Comment: I tried that and it moves the accordion back behind the text ontop of it not being clickable.